# Obtaining build status of a jenkins job which is remotely built using java

Tags: java, rest, jenkins

I am triggering a job remotely using java, I need to trigger another job only after the build of first job is finished/completed(irrespective of the build being successful or not). How to obtain the status of the first build.

I have referred this to trigger jobs remotely. 
https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/226852648-How-to-build-a-job-using-the-REST-API-and-Java

Comment: If you get the build number back from the request, use `<jenkins-instance>/job/<your job name>/<build number>/api/json` to poll. It will contain a property `building` and a property `result`

Comment: @Rik how to get the build number back from the request?

Comment: That was more a question. I can imagine that if you start a build over the api, you get the buildnumbet back in the response

Comment: @Rik Thanks a lot buddy, I worked along your idea and it served my purpose.

Comment: Glad it helped. Maybe you can post how you solved it, so other people can benefit from it as well.